# Accessing property values within filename-generator-expression

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have the following snippet in one of our Spring Batch XML files:

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
id="out" directory="c:\test" 
filename-generator-expression="headers['msg.number']+'.xml'" 
channel="in"/>
```

We would like to add access a value stored in a property file from within `filename-generator-expression`

The property can be accessed elsewhere in the XML as follows: `attribute="${property.name}"`

Th question is, how to access it from within `filename-generator-expression`.

This is obviously wrong:

```
filename-generator-expression="${property.name} + headers['msg.number']+'.xml'"
```

What is the correct solution?

Thanks very much

Comment: One thing that is wrong with your reasoning. The property isn't accessed it is just replaced, the `${...}` indicates a placeholder which is replaced at configuration time. From SpEL you should be able to access the `Environment` and use that to get the property.

Comment: Thanks, but I must have the syntax wrong - tried this but does not work: filename-generator-expression="#{systemProperties['property.name']}+headers['msg.number']+'.xml'"

Comment: try filename-generator-expression="#{systemProperties['property.name']+headers['msg‌​.number']+'.xml'}

Comment: That isn't the environment those are the system properties. Try `@environment.getProperty('your.property')` instead of `systemProperties`.